# Do you need all the historic previous values to calculate EMA?

Tags: php, moving-average, trading, indicator

I'm calculating EMA for some prices series using PHP.

[Moving Averages in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)
[WHAT IS EMA?](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ema.asp)

Imagine that you have an array with 5000 elements, and you want to calculate EMA 10.

Compated with SMA, in SMA you only need to get the last 10 values and calculate the average, but in EMA you need the previous EMA value for new calculation. First EMA value is the SMA number of elements required.

My question is, do you need to process the 5000 previous values for EMA?

As i said it uses the previous value for next calculation, in theory you must but it can be a problem when you have for example 5 millions of registers.

Or is it just enough to get the items from $n-20 to $n-11, calculate the SMA, and then apply EMA for last 10 values?.

Additionally old values is EMA are deprecated faster, because it uses Alpha for that. I have created the next function to calculate EMA:

```
function EMA($v,$lastvalue,$num=200)
{

    if($num>(count($v)-1))
        return FALSE;        
    $MA=0;    
    $initMA=count($v)-2*$num;
    if($initMA<0)
        $initMA=0;
    for($i=0,$j=$initMA;$i<$num;$i++,$j++)
        $MA+=$v[$j];
    $EMA=$MA/$num;
    $a = 2/ ($num + 1);
    for($i=$j;$i<count($v)-1;$i++)
        $EMA = $a * $v[$i+1]+ (1-$a) * $EMA;
    $EMA = $a * $lastvalue+ (1-$a) * $EMA;
    return $EMA;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what EMA and SMA are, don't assume we know your jargon or business area. Also from what you've written this question seems to be more about the discussing actual correct formula for whatever calculation you're trying to make, rather than anything specific to PHP. If that's the case, it would be better to ask a community of experts in that particular business or maths domain. Once you've clarified the formula, you can talk to programmers about how to implement it

Comment: I suggest to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-ema.php instead. It's based on https://www.ta-lib.org/

Comment: @ADyson now you have links where it is explained.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the tip but i would like to code it by myself and know does it works, anyways i need to pass an array to the function with the values and i need to know if i need to pass all them or only the last 2*num values.

Comment: @Gordon anyways thanks for the tip, i didnt know about this library https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php and i will take a look, anyways you still need to know how it works to calculate it right.

Comment: @ADyson based in your thoughs, everything can be explained by experts in particular business... and any algorithm by maths experts... , i have tagged php because i'm doint it in php, language is not important, but the question is, and there are a lot of stuff about EMA and SMA in stack overflow already..., but now that i have asked.

Comment: `language is not important`... then don't ask a programming question, go and ask on the maths stackexchange instead if you just want to know the formula. Like I said, implementation in a specific language is something you can sort out once you understand the calculations necessary - once you can understand the calculations and do it on paper, then you can think about coding it. If your question _is_ about the code implementation, then it needs clarifying specifically what the issue is, but it sounds more like you just don't know the proper calculation to use.

Comment: @ADyson in a lot of algorithms language is not important, just the algorithm...

Comment: @Gordon it is a windows only extension, using ubuntu here

Comment: @hamboy75 it's not windows only

Comment: `a lot of algorithms language is not important, just the algorithm`... yes, that was my point. So if you're unsure of the algorithm or calculation, the PHP code is not important at this time. You've asked an overall question about the algorithm but then focused the details on the PHP, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with EMA20 in long series of numbers with known ema20 results, and comparing values with my algoritm, and yes, you need all the values since the begining.

In EMA with a lot of numbers like EMA200 it is not important, since old values weight is really small, but in small EMAs when high volatility it is important to calculate the ema using all the values in the historic.

So an efficient algorithm would need to store all those previous emas in a file or a database, since calculate the current ema would generate a lot of calculations, and if you have them already calculated it is just one simple operation.